# Slicing a URL with javascript method .split( )

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to set up a referral program for users of a site. Each one currently gets a referral link like this: `mysite.app/user/signup/?ref=123456789`

On each signup, I need to slice that URL ?ref parameter `123456789`, assign it to the variable `ref` and push it to a form input field with the `id=hiddenref`.

I have the script below from a tutorial but I can't get it to work and I suspect it might be because it was meant for a URL with a folder structure like this: `mysite.app/?ref=123456789`.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
<script> 
var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1),
        sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
        sParameterName,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

        if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
            return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : decodeURIComponent(sParameterName[1]);
        }
        else return "none";
    }
};

ref = getUrlParameter('ref'); 
document.getElementById('hiddenref').value = ref;
</script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

You can use URL class

```
var u = new URL(location.href);
u.searchParams.get("ref")
```

it will return

```
123456789
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below util method.

```js
const getQueryParams = url => {
  const match = url.split(/\/?\?|#/)[1];
  if (!match) return;
  return match.split(/&/g).reduce((m, v) => {
    const [key, val] = v.split("=");
    m[key] = val;
    return m;
  }, {});
};
const params = getQueryParams(
  "https://flank.xyz/contact/thank-you/?loginId=xsf234-22f8-48d3-c3d3-08d7c7f8b488&tag=17&xyz=123#&xyz=456"
);
console.log(params.xyz);
console.log(params.loginId);

const params2 = getQueryParams(
  "https://flank.xyz/contact/thank-you/?loginId=xsf234-22f8-48d3-c3d3-08d7c7f8b488&tag=17&xyz=123"
);
console.log(params2.xyz);
console.log(params2.loginId);
```

```css
.as-console-row {color: blue!important}
```

Comment: It seems incomplete to me as it doesn't handle the URL fragment part correctly: `getQueryParams('http://example.com/abc?xyz=123#')` is `{x: '123#'}` instead of `{x: '123'}`, `getQueryParams('http://example.com/abc?xyz=123#&xyz=456')` is `{x: '456'}` instead of `{x: '123'}`

Comment: haha. let me update, He doesn't had that case.

Comment: True but it looks like a generic utility function to extract a query from an URL, not from "the OP's URL only", so it would be best if it would actually work on any URL, since other people than the OP may find it in the search/on Google!

Comment: oh and may I add that it would be good to add `decodeURIComponent` to the values...!

Comment: @CherryDTUpdated solution, Too much over engineering. i don't like :-D

Comment: @CherryDT @xdeepakv thanks for the help. I've tried to make it work, but my input field ends up with "[Object object]" using this:  

`<script>
  const getQueryParams = url => {
    const match = url.split(/\/?\?|#/)[1];
    if (!match) return;
    return match.split(/&/g).reduce((m, v) => {
      const [key, val] = v.split("=");
      m[key] = val;
      return m;
    }, {});
  };
  const params = getQueryParams(window.location.search);
  document.getElementById('hiddenref').value = params;
</script>`

Am I grabbing the URL in the wrong way with `window.location.search`?

Comment: You have to get desire tag: params.ref
`const params = getQueryParams(window.location.search); document.getElementById('hiddenref').value = params.ref;
`

Comment: That worked! I'm no JS expert, but do you think this would be more robust? 

`function getParameterByName(name, url) {
      if (!url) url = window.location.href;
      name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\\$&');
      var regex = new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)'),
          results = regex.exec(url);
      if (!results) return null;
      if (!results[2]) return '';
      return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
  }
  let ref = getParameterByName('ref');
  document.getElementById('hiddenref').value = ref;`

Comment: This was mentioned in this post: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript) as the right solution.

Answer (score -1):

The hacky, easiest way:

```js
let ref = window.location.split('?ref=')[1]
```

This is obviously prone to error. A much better way is [described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript).